# How to stop all threads that entered SwingWorker.process method until user makes choice in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have such problem. Many `SwingWorker`s are executing simultaneously. They all process published chunks of data in `SwingWorker.process` method.

I need to stop all threads when first thread processes first chunk of data in `SwingWorker.process` method.

Because I need to ask user what to do with found chunk of data only once. I need to notify user that such files are found and I need to ask him what to do with found files.

For now my `SwingWorker.process` method is:

```
private static volatile Integer userOption = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    @Override
        protected void process(final List<Path> chunks) {    
            if (userOption == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                // to prevent all other SwingWorkers from doing smth until user makes a choice
                userOption = -100;
                userOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(MainFrame.getInstance().getFrame(),
                        "New viruses where detected!\r\n\r\n Please choose your action:", "Delete or view viruses",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "Delete viruses",
                                "Show in table" }, "Delete viruses");

            }
            if (userOption == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                VirusManager.deleteViruses(chunks);
    }
```

I don't show `SwingWorker.doInBackground` method because it only traverses system file tree and publishes file after file.

How to stop all `SwingWorker`s until user makes a choice in `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`?

Comment: This method is perfectly fine, in fact you don't even need the `userOption = -100;` or the volatility. This is due to the fact that all `process` calls are *on the same thread*, namely the **EDT**. Only problem I see is that you continue background work even if user clicks "No".

Comment: How I continue background work? If user clicks NO then `userOption !=OK_OPTION`

Comment: That just means `process` will not do anything. However `doInBackground` will not stop. If you want to stop the `doInBackground` methods, then you should clarify that in the question...

Comment: from code posted here isn't possible to ..., please whats are are executing simultaneously., voting to close as too broad, btw you have to naming every instances with unique identifier in the case that there is running more than one instance, use Runnable#Thread for real production code, rather than playing with shadowing methods in Future and SwingWorker

Comment: btw JOptionPane stopping execution of code untill is visible on the screen, have to test in JProfiler